# C++ member initialization from derived class to base class

Tags: c++

Let's see the following C++ codes.
Each inherited class has its member variables and initialization function.
These member variables are some different(almost same type) between inherited classes.
Is there any good way to move (or merge) this initialization into base class?

```
class Base {
public:
   virtual init() = 0;
}
class A: public Base {
public:
   int a1;
   void init() { a1 = 0;}
}
class B: public Base {
public:
   int b1;
   void init() { b1 = 1;}
}
```

Comment: There's no constructor here, just a random function named `init()`. Is that what you're intending? Also if each of the subclasses have different variables to set you cannot possibly move or merge that into the base class, as the base class has no idea what the subclasses need done, nor should it.

Comment: Yeah, you probably want to read about constructors in C++. Not quite sure what you're trying to do here. Just in case: If you wanted to initialize `a1` and `b1` in the constructor of the base class `Base` this should not be possible in C++ as it does not support reflection - somebody please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Having an init functions instead of a constructor means you can construct an uninitialized object. This means you are forever having to ask "Has this object been initialized?" This sucks performance and allows avoidable bugs. Use the constructor and throw an exception on failure so you never have an uninitialized object. For further reading, [familiarize yourself with RAII.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)

Comment: No return type for the Base::init(), no semicolons at the end of class definitions.  It is highly recommended to explicitly write virtual (and override).  Adding constructor(s) and virtual destructor would be nice, too.

Answer (score 4):

No. `Base` has no knowledge of `A::a1` or `B::b1`. More importantly it ***should not*** have any knowledge of it's subclass members as this leads to a fundamental breakdown of the encapsulation you're trying to achieve in the first place.

The best you can do is have your `Base` class define a virtual method for initialisation and control when that method is called. It is up to each subclass to override the method and ensure that when initialisation is needed it is performed according to each subclass's respective requirements.

One thing to note is that if your initialisation is intended to be once-off for the lifetime of each object, the the correct place to do this is using constructors as per [koizyd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937853/224704).

---

On a related note, I'd like to point out that what you're asking is a variation on one of the most common OO design flaws I've seen in my career.

*Using inheritance for code reuse not encapsulation.*

Basically you're trying to push functionality into the base class (for reuse), and all this really achieves is making the Base class large, top-heavy and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ we can't (almost always) create function init, we use constructors
e.g

```
class Base {
};
class A : public Base {
public:
    int a1;
    A():Base(), a1(0) {}
};
class B : public Base {
public:
    int b1;
    B():Base(), b1(1){}
};
```

Construct "child" is `A():Base(),a1(0)`, it's initializer list (`:Base(),a1(0)`), which create `Base` object, and `int b1`.
You should remember about `;` after class.

Comment: if you give some downvote, you can describe disadvantage solution.

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably structure code like this:

```
class Base {
public:
   void init() { sub_init(); }
protected:
   virtual void sub_init() = 0;
}
class A: public Base {
public:
   int a1;
protected:
   void sub_init() { a1 = 0;}
}
class B: public Base {
public:
   int b1;
protected:
   void sub_init() { b1 = 1;}
}
```

The alternative of doing something like (syntax probably not correct...):

```
class Base {
public:
   virtual void init() = 0;
protected:
   void generic_init<T>(T &foo, T const &bar) { foo = bar; }
}
class A: public Base {
public:
   int a1;
   void init() { generic_init<int>(a1, 0); }
}
class B: public Base {
public:
   int b1;
   void init() { generic_init<int>(b1, 1); }
}
```

Looks awful to me!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use the template class skills to solve the problem. Like:

```
template <typename T> class Base {
public :
  virtual void init( T t ) = 0;
};

class A: public Base<T> {
public:
   T a1;
   void init( T t ) { a1 = t;}
}

class B: public Base<T> {
public:
   T b1;
   void init( T t ) { b1 = t;}
}
```

You could have a try.